# Facebook SDK not supported by compiler error (iOS / Xcode)?

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I am trying to install the Facebook SDK for making Instagram ads but when importing the SDK "import FBSDKCoreKit" I get the following error below.

**Failed to build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.**

I installed the SDK with Cocoapods and also added the correct information info.plist.

Any idea how to fix this? I am using the latest XCode Version 13.4.1

[image]